# How to use QList to keep track of instances of child classes

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have two classes, `Parent` and `Child` (the latter is derived from the former) , and these are both QObject derived classes. These classes are implemented as nodes on a tree structure, giving each node its specific functionality. Under the `Parent` class there is a signal that creates a new object of type `Child` whenever triggered. So after three triggers the tree structure would look like this:

PARENT

---------Child 1

---------Child (1)

---------Child (2)

How would I use `QList` to keep track of the number of child objects created? I want to append the index number with the name so that `Child (1)` would look like `Child 1`, it looks like a copy now.

I have read the `QList` documentation and I understand how to extract meaningful information once the objects are in a list, but it's this part that I can't find an answer to.

EDIT:

Say I did `QList<Child*>ListID`, would this just initialise `ListID` as a pointer to a list of type `Parent`, or would it also populate that list?

Any suggestions?

PS: I wanted to know this before I started implementation, as I want to know if I am going about it in the wrong way. That is why I have no code to show. I was hoping for more of a casual discussion.

Comment: I don't understand your question, especially "I want to append the index number with the name so that Child (1) would look like Child 1, it looks like a copy now." what looks like a copy? Why can't You just hold a `QList<Child>` member in `Parent` class?

Comment: So adding `QList<Child*>SomeId` in `Parent`would create a list of children accessible by the parent? I sound really stupid but I haven't used QList before. Also `Child (1)` looks like a copy of `Child` as opposed to `Child 1`. This example was just arbitrary. I need the list for more elaborate functionalities.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "looks like a copy" but yes, `QList<Child*>SomeId` is the way to go, you allocate an object, append a pointer to the list and you have a "child" which You can track. Remember to take care of deleting the children when appropriate. If the `Child` class is simple then probably using `QList<Child>` would be simpler.

Comment: @MichaelThomas sorry for offtopic, but last week you are asking a lot of newbie questions. You need to read something about programming at all. Because you have no understanding of what you are doing. Especially, read something about C++ and it's features. Now about subject: use smart pointers, for example `QSharedPointer` or `std::shared_ptr` as items of your container.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I am truly sorry about that. I try to make my doubts as specific as possible, and I am genuinely trying not to spam. The questions are newbie because I am just starting to learn. I am not expecting straight up solutions either; a link to any reading material would fit the bill perfectly. It's just too vast unless someone points me in the right direction. Also I try and solve my questions too, rather than wait for an answer. I hope I haven't blacklisted myself from asking anymore questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bare `QObject` itself is a tree node. **Yes, a `QObject` is a container of `QObject`s!** So, you need to do nothing special at all, since it keeps a list of all of its direct children, and also provides a way to recursively get all children of a particular type or name.

To access the list of children, use `QObject::children()`. To get only the children of a specific type, use `QObject::findChildren()`.

In your case, you can invoke `auto list = findChildren<Child*>({}, Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly)` to get the list when you need it. If you care not to dynamically allocate any memory, use `QObject`'s internal list directly:

```
for (auto objChild : std::as_const(children()))
  if (auto child = qobject_cast<Child*>(objChild)) {
    ...
  }
```

*Pre C++-17, use `qAsConst` instead of `std::as_const`.*

If you're sure that only objects of a particular type are children, you can use a `static_cast` instead and save a tiny bit of runtime:

```
for (auto objChild : std::as_const(children())) {
  auto child = static_cast<Child*>(objChild);
  ...
}
```

> Under the `Parent` class there is a **signal** that creates a new object of type `Child` whenever triggered.

Presumably you meant a slot?

Comment: I did. I was trying to say that there is a `triggered()` signal connected to a slot that creates a new instance of type `Child` Also, just to clarify, I will be able to treat `list` as a normal array type object? Like to get the total count and indices.

Comment: Before I answer: look at its type - look what type `findChildren` returns, and then see what operations and properties that type supports. Furthermore, due to range-for, you many not need to care at all whether `list` can even give you a total count or indices, if all you need is to walk it (iterate over its elements).